# What is the difference between חרמין וההקדשות

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, maseches-rosh-hashana, hekdesh

What is the difference between חרמין וההקדשות?

Since they are both making something the property of the Temple Treasury

(actually there is a machlokes between Rashi and Tosfos see Rosh Hashana 4a)

In Rosh Hashana 4a (on the bottom in the braisa) mentions both of these things.

What is the difference between them?

Maybe something in Halacha?

Comment: Definition of Hekdesh http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0008_0_08693.html

Comment: You could make this question more answerable by editing in more information about where these terms come up.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Rosh Hashana 4a at the bottom Tanu Rabbonon

Answer (score 2):

According to [Mishneh Torah Erechin V'Charamin 6:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/6406.htm), הקדש goes to the Temple treasury by default, but חרם goes to the Kohanim by default unless the person consecrating it specifies that it is to go to the temple treasury.

This is based on Numbers 18:14 which gives "All *cherem* in Israel" to the Kohanim.

Comment: This is a machloket tannaim (if stam charamim lakohanim or levedek habayit; see erchin 8:6). Do you know that the cited gemara in rosh hashana holds that stam charamim lakohanim? Rashi there seems to imply the opposite.

Comment: No, I took a shortcut and went straight to the Rambam, in part because I assumed he distilled the meaning overall from all places it's discussed and in part because I seem to remember the machlokes being decided in the Gemara in Erchin. BTW, is there a "challenger" badge? Your poking and prodding at practically every answer really helps the overall quality of the site.